# Weird table size in PhpMyAdmin database overview

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This problem persists since "years". Currently I have PMA 4.6.1. The values under the `Size` column have very weird values. I could not find anything regarding this in the internet.

`Metro` theme:
[image]

`Original` theme:
[image]

Any idea what is going wrong?

**Update:**

The table `app_codes` has this structure and as you can see it has only 2 rows.
[image]

When you check the displayed number you see the decimal point is **before** the thousand separator...

**Update:**

As suggested I ran the `repair` command but `app_codes` did not really changed. `app_codes_items` seems to be fixed.
[image]

**Update:**

As requested the output for `SHOW TABLE STATUS`:
[image]

Comment: That's a big table. Your hard drive must be huge! MyISAM is a pretty wobbly database engine. You may need to repair your tables and check again.

Comment: @tadman I ran it. Question is updated.

Comment: Can you pls run a show table status command app_codes table and check what it returns as the size? This test determines if this is a phpmyadmin display issue or a mysql issue.

Comment: @Shadow Updated. For me it looks like a PMA issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer `nijel` posted my question as issue on [github](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12303) and he mentioned something regarding *rounding problem*.

I remembered that I have in my `php.ini` this setting: `precision = 20`

After playing around I found out that the value of `20` causes this issue. Up to the value `16` the size is displayed correctly. Above `16` the weird size output starts.

**Update:** phpMyAdmin team member wrote me in the meantime to confirm this bug has been fixed in the new release 4.6.3.